# i could not echo the value of certain id present in an array in the foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

my view:

```
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Students</th>
              <th>Attendance Percentage (%)</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
      <tbody>
  <?php
    $stid=array();
   foreach($students as $row){
      array_push($stid, $row['student_id']);
        ?>

  <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['student_id'];  ?> </td>
      <?php 
      $per=array();
      $a='';
       foreach ($percent as $key => $value) : 
      array_push($per, $key); 
     if(in_array($per, $stid)){if($per==$stid){ $a = $value[$key];}  else{ $a = "100"; } } 
     ?> <td><?php echo $a; ?></td><?php endforeach;?>

     </tr>

      <?php   }   ?>    
      </tbody>
      </table>
```

and I have the controller

```
$data['students'] = $this->Student_model->get_student_id($dep, $sem, $bat, $div);
$attendance = $this->Department_model->get_student_attendance_only($sub, $sem, $bat); 
$counts = array () ;
foreach ( $attendance as $row ) {
    $sub = explode(',', $row['attendance']);
    foreach ( $sub as $subval ) {
        if ( array_key_exists ( $subval, $counts ) ) {
            $counts[$subval] ++ ;
        } else {
            $counts[$subval] = 1 ;
        }
    } 
}

$st_ids=array();
foreach ($counts as $key => $value) {
    $days_present[$key] = 120 - $counts[$key];
    array_push($present, $days_present[$key] );
    array_push($st_ids, $key );
}

$percentage = array();
foreach ($present as  $value) {
    $result = (($value * 100)/ 120);
    $result = round($result);
    array_push($percentage, $result);
    array_push($per, $value);
}

$all = array_combine($st_ids, $percentage);
$data['percent'] = $all;
```

This is passed to the view. $percent has a $key => $value pair. this is where i am finding difficulty to echo the corresponding key's value in the table. if there is no matching id in this array, then I want to echo a default value, else i want to echo its corresponding key-value. Appreciate if anyone could help me to sort this out.

Comment: dump $students first. are u getting records from db?

Comment: yes..and $students contains all the data i require..for eg, student id, student name ..

Comment: And i have array pushed the student ids in $stid array as well..

Comment: I guess ---foreach($students as $row){
      array_push($stid, $row['student_id']);
        ?>-- created more indexes so you might have to access it like $row[0]['student_id'] or the index you want to access

Comment: Well,  the foreach($students as $row) echoes the correct number of data in the <td>. The issue is with the second foreach which has the student id as its key

Comment: What I want is:  if the key is in the array $stid, then echo the $value else echo as "100";

Comment: <td><?php echo $row['student_id'];  ?> </td> this statement is not in any loop , how will it print any index

Comment: thanks @Adrian Bobrowski for edit. julie thats very complex logic you are creating. you could have done all that in model and just render the results here

Comment: Thanks for your help..i sorted it by swapping the foreach loops and then echoing the values...

Comment: This is what I did:    <tbody>
      <?php
      $per=array();
foreach ($percent as $key => $value) { 
  array_push($per, $key); 
}
       foreach($students as $row){
?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name'];  ?> </td>
<td><?php if(in_array($row['student_id'], $per)){ echo $value.'%'; } else {echo "100%";  }?></td>
</tr>
  
  <?php  }   ?>    
          </tbody>

Comment: see ur post now

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Please never post an answer as a comment.  Also, do not add question details in a comment.  Please post your solution as an answer and mark it with a green tick.

Comment: @mickmackusa...will do that next time...I am new to this forum ...I am just learning the Do's and Dont's..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either filter the final array in the controller itself or can do it in the view as follows:

```
   <tbody>  <?php $per=array();foreach($percent as $key=>$value) {array_push($per, $key); }foreach($students as $row){ ?> <tr> <td><?php echo row['name']; ?> </td> <td><?php if(in_array($row['student_id'], $per)){ echo  $value.'%'; } else {echo "100%"; }?></td> </tr> <?php } ?> </tbody>
```